# Deploying multi-module appengine projects using service account

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, continuous-integration

All of my previous appengine projects were single module. I deploy them using gcloud since, as far as I know, this is the only tool supporting service account authentication (vs AppCfg & appengine maven plugin), which is a requirement for me.

I am now creating my first java multi-module project and based it on this sample: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java

However, when I try to deploy the project, I get a

```
Bad argument: The requested action does not support EAR configurations
AppCfg [options] stage <app-dir> <staging-dir>
```

From what I understand, gcloud uses AppCfg to generate yaml configuration files and it does not support EAR configurations.

Is there a way to deploy this kind of project using a tool that supports service accounts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run `mvn package` to build the WAR folders of the modules (`appengine-modules-guestbook/target/appengine-modules-guestbook-1-1.0`, for example, given the link you posted). Once you've built those WAR folders, deploy them individually with [`mvn gcloud:deploy`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-maven-plugin) (read about this maven plugin at the link provided)

Comment: I am currently doing that using `mvn --projects <module> gcloud:deploy`. It works, but adding a new module requires me to change my deploy jobs.

Comment: If you add a new module, you'll have a new payload to send to the automated-deployment server, so you might as have your deployment script search for modules within the project directory and iterate over them with `mvn --projects <module> gcloud:deploy`